# Using input type="radio" in thymeleaf template for multiple choices depending on category

Tags: html, spring-boot, web-applications, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf template that looks like this(I'm going to post only the problematic part)

```
            <tr>
                <td>Bonus Vacation Day:</td>
                <td>
                    <ul>

                        <li><strong>Parent</strong></li>
                        <li th:each="pbd : ${parentBonusDays}">
                            <input th:type="radio" th:field="*{bonusVacationDays}" name="bonusCategory1" th:value="${pbd.id}" th:text="${pbd.getDescription()}"/>
                        </li>

                        <li><strong>Disability</strong></li>
                        <li>
                            <div th:each="dbd : ${disabilityBonusDays}">
                                <input th:type="radio" th:field="*{bonusVacationDays}" name="bonusCategory2" th:value="${dbd.id}" th:text="${dbd.getDescription()}"/>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li><strong>Work Experience</strong></li>
                        <li>
                            <div th:each="we : ${workExperience}">
                                <input th:type="radio" th:field="*{bonusVacationDays}" name="bonusCategory3" th:value="${we.id}" th:text="${we.getDescription()}"/>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

and this is the controller

```
    @GetMapping("/save")
    public String showAddEmployeeForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        model.addAttribute("departmentList", departmentService.getAllDepartments());
        model.addAttribute("roles", Role.values());
        model.addAttribute("vacationDays", vacationDayService.vacationDaysCategories());
        model.addAttribute("parentBonusDays", bonusVacationDayService.findByDescriptionContaining("parent"));
        model.addAttribute("disabilityBonusDays", bonusVacationDayService.findByDescriptionContaining("disability"));
        model.addAttribute("workExperience", bonusVacationDayService.findByDescriptionContaining("experience"));

        return "employee-create";
    }
```

I want to be able to select one choice per group but instead I'm only allowed to select one choice in total(for example if I select an option for Parent and then for Work Experience, it excludes the selection for Parent).
I tought this is going to work for sure but it doesn't.
[image]

Model:

> ```
> @ManyToMany
> @JoinTable(
>         name = "employee_bonus_vacation_day_join_table",
>         joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bonus_vacation_day_id"),
>         inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
> )
> private List<BonusVacationDay> bonusVacationDays;
> ```

Comment: Your template binds them to the same `th:field` which will result in a single group. So no this isn't going to work as you expected. You would need multiple fields (for multiple groups) to bind to.

Comment: I feel I should add the model also so It can be seen how it's mapped
so i edited the post

Comment: Regardless, it is a radio button. For which you can only have 1 active for a group, that is the whole idea of a readio button. Else use a checkbox instead.

Comment: Can I achieve what I want with checkbox? (I've tried that also)
Do I need to write javascript code in order to select only 1 check per group

Comment: It is either that or use different groups/ids for the radioboxes.